# Python create unique instances of a tkinter class from a list with parameters

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm helping clean up some code for a senior design project. The students have a python app that is using tkinter to create a GUI for inventory control and vending product. I don't want to post a ton of code but hope to portray what I'm trying to do.

Description of what is below:
BinA, BinB, BinC,and BinD are all the same but with unique variable passed in, A bin class was created in a new document called pages.py. These are created at the bottom of the main program with their variables. Then I put them in a framesList along with other pages the application will navigate through. All the other frames in the list are currently unique hard-coded classes in the code or we will want to apply the solution I'm struggling with if we get it working.

When Bin(A-D) all had unique hard-coded self named classes that had identical code in them other than the few parameters we identified, screen navigation operated as expected, but creating 4 instances of pages.bin and iterating through the list of frames results in only having what appears to be 4 pages.bin with only the last created variables. You can see after `for F in frameList:` the show `self.show_frame(BinA)` is called, but the first element in the LinkList is a string the populates a label on the screen. This label only show what ever the last frame was created of the Pages.bin. type. The other screen are all created correctly and function. Just navigating back to screen Bin(?) always behaves like BinD in this case. If I create them in reverse order D,C,B,A then BinA is the result for all four.

I suspect what is happeing is we are only creating one instance of pages.Bin and simply overwriting it in each loop of `for F in frameList:` but the other are ok because they are all unique Classes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import csv
import openpyxl
import pages

#get Display Size
root = tk.Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth() #1440
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight() #900
#Close the popup
root.destroy()

print('Width: %i px, height: %i px' %(screen_width, screen_height))


#Create the main Application
class CMGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "CMA: AutoBox")
        tk.Tk.wm_resizable(self,0,0)
        tk.Tk.wm_overrideredirect(self,False)#True) //Use this on the final
        container = tk.Frame(self)       
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        

        self.frames = {}

        #Declart the Objects

        # Put them in a List
        frameList =    [[BinA       ,BinA_linksList],
                        [BinB       ,BinB_linksList],
                        [BinC       ,BinC_linksList],
                        [BinD       ,BinD_linksList],
                        [HomePage   ,None],
                        [PPE        ,None],
                        [Weld       ,None],
                        [Misc       ,None],
                        [Set        ,None],
                        [PPE2       ,None],
                        [Weld2      ,None],
                        [Misc2      ,None],
                        [AllItems   ,None],
                        [BinType    ,None],
                        [Inventory  ,None],
                        [LoginPage  ,None]]

        for F in frameList:             
        #   frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            frame = F[0](container, self, F[1])
            self.frames[F[0]] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.configure(bg='deepskyblue')


        self.show_frame(BinA) 
....
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ....

class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ....

class AllItems(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        .....

ALLOT OF other CODE creating the other page classes like BinType, HomePage, PPE, and more
....

#Create 4 pages for bins
# Bin? = pages.Bin
# Bin?_linkList = ["Label"  ,return_Link ,Link_1    ,Link_2     ,Link_3     ,Link_4]

BinA = pages.Bin
BinA_linksList = ["Bin A"   ,BinType    ,HomePage   ,PPE        ,PPE        ,PPE]

BinB = pages.Bin
BinB_linksList = ["Bin B"   ,BinType    ,PPE        ,HomePage   ,PPE    ,PPE]

BinC = pages.Bin
BinC_linksList = ["Bin C"   ,BinType    ,PPE        ,PPE        ,HomePage   ,PPE]

BinD = pages.Bin
BinD_linksList = ["Bin D"   ,BinType    ,PPE        ,PPE        ,PPE    ,HomePage]


w = str(screen_width)
h = str(screen_height)
z = str("+0+0")
screenres = w+'x'+h+z

app = CMGUI()
app.geometry(screenres)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy
```

**pages.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Bin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, data):
     
        print(data[0])
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        # Header Label        
        tk.Label(self, font=('times', 50, 'bold'), 
            text=data[0], fg="deepskyblue", bd=20, anchor='center', 
            bg="black", relief="ridge").place(anchor = "n", relx = .5, y =0)
        
        # Footer Label
        tk.Label(self, font=('times',22,'bold'), 
            text="Page 1", bg="deepskyblue", fg="black").place(anchor = "s", relx = .5, rely = .95)

        #Buttons:
        #mylist =   [["Title"]                  , page      , "anchor"  , %x    ,  %y   ],
        btnList =   [["Search By\n Bin Type"    , data[0]   , "ne"      , .95   , .05   ],
                    ["Back to\n Categories"     , data[1]   , "nw"      , .05   , .05   ]]
                    
        for b in btnList:
            tk.Button(self, padx=5, pady=5, bd=16, fg="white", font=('times',24,'bold'), width=8, height=2,
                  text=b[0], bg="black", relief="raised",
                  command = lambda i=b[1]: controller.show_frame(i)).place(anchor = b[2],relx = b[3], rely = b[4])

        btnList2 =   [["Item 1"   , data[2]   , "se"      , .5   , .5   ],
                     ["Item 2"    , data[3]   , "sw"      , .5   , .5   ],
                     ["Item 3"    , data[4]   , "ne"      , .5   , .5   ],
                     ["Item 4"    , data[5]   , "nw"      , .5   , .5   ]]
                
        for b in btnList2:
            tk.Button(self, padx=5, pady=5, bd=16, fg="white", font=('times',24,'bold'), width=9, height=3,
                  text=b[0], bg="black", relief="raised",
                  command = lambda i=b[1]: controller.show_frame(i)).place(anchor = b[2],relx = b[3], rely = b[4])
```

Comment: This isn't the issue, but in the `__init__` functions, you should be using `super()` instead. example: `tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` change to: `super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`
Also try to remote the glob imports it is risky. (i.e. get rid of the `from tkinter import *`)

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn Those are called "wildcard imports" and are expressly recommended against in PEP8. Also you need to remove self from the super() call, and Tk has no args so you can remove that too.

Comment: @Novel thank you for the corrections I had equated `*` to glob and thought wildcard was a broader definition. Unfortunately the tkinter documentation is encouraging people to use "wildcard imports" despite PEP8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BinA, BinB, BinC,and BinD are all literally the same object: Bin. To boil down your code to simplest terms, what do you expect the output of this is?

```
data = 'spam'
BinA = data
BinB = data
BinC = data
BinD = data

frames = {}
for F in (BinA, BinB, BinC, BinD):
    frames[F] = 42

print(frames) # what do you expect this to print?
```

Try that and see, and you'll understand your problem.

The simple solution is to replace

```
BinA = pages.Bin
```

with

```
class BinA(pages.Bin): pass
```

Thereby creating a unique object.

But that's not clean at all. To clean it you would pick a different metric to store your pages with, and at the same time move to a modern inheritance style and remove the useless controller frame.

Comment: This Solved it THANKS! I definitely want to try the other too just for completeness.

Comment: would there be a way that I could Dynamically from a list change the name of BinA to #name. I could then have a list of myClasses = [BinA, BinB, ... BinN] and then use  a for n in myClasses: class n(pages.Bin); pass     I would like to create a unknow number or instances determined from a external Spreadsheet.

Comment: @CoreyApplegate do it correctly then and store the frames using the name or instance or something else that's not the actual class.